# How to speed up GroupAggregate

Tags: explain, postgresql-12, timescaledb

https://explain.depesz.com/s/I2IN

I have a query against a TimescaleDB 1.7 hypertable on Postgresql 12.

Lots of joins to other table. When I do the grouping it seems to take a lot of time, I switched the grouping to using an id but it didn't seem to improve my query that much.

- I see that it's using external merging disk, is this the reason the grouping is so slow?
- Is this a consequence of the size of telemetry table? And the fact that I use uuid for joining?

How to improve this without increase work_mem ?

```
                                   Table "tracking.telemetry"
         Column         |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |      Default
------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 time                   | timestamp with time zone    |           | not null |
 vehicle_vin            | text                        |           | not null |
 unit_uuid              | uuid                        |           |          |
Indexes:
    "telemetry_time_idx" btree ("time" DESC)
    "telemetry_unit_time_idx" btree (unit_uuid, "time")
    "telemetry_vin_idx" btree (vehicle_vin)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "telemetry_unit_uuid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (unit_uuid) REFERENCES unit(uuid)


                                 Table "public.vehicle"
      Column       |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |      Default
-------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 vin               | text                     |           | not null |
 device_identifier | text                     |           |          |
Indexes:
    "vehicle_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (vin)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "vehicle_device_identifier_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (device_identifier) REFERENCES communication_device(identifier)

                              Table "public.last_shadow"
     Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |      Default
----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 identifier     | text                     |           | not null |
 flatten_data   | jsonb                    |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "last_shadow_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (identifier)

                                        Table "public.unit"
    Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |             Default
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 client_number | text                     |           | not null |
 vehicle_vin   | text                     |           |          |
 uuid          | uuid                     |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
Indexes:
    "unit_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uuid)
    "unit_vehicle_vin_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_vin) REFERENCES vehicle(vin) DEFERRABLE
```

Comment: External merge is much like Merge sort. It is used when the data does not fit in memory. This is probably the slowest sort method since there is lot of disk thrashing involved i.e it takes data from disk sorts it and then puts it back, it takes total table data/memory it can fit.

See more here: https://www.cnblogs.com/xiaotengyi/p/7234998.html